# cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() return 0 after visual studio build and with_cuda is set true for opencv using windows10

Tags: windows-10, gpu, visual-studio, cuda, opencv

I want gpu to work in opencv , after CMake with_cuda true and build of (ALL_Build, Install) with no errors
I found GPU not detected
I use windows 10 I tried 3 times to build opencv , but Gpu not work and cuda is ticked in CMake
`cv.__version__` is working

[image]

Comment: is there any help I am trying from week ago

Comment: you ever find a solution? I have the same problem! Windows 10. VS2019. I'm using newest git, and C++.